# @Input property is not being updated second time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm creating a reusable component which can be shown from any external component, but can be hidden using a function in same component, but somehow the property change in parent component is not updating child.

Here is the stackblitz for the same.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfjkmu

I need "Show" button should show the component all the time and I can hide the component using "hide" button any time.

Comment: I update the code and add some explain for you. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need sync value from child to parent using `Output`

```
  @Input()
  show = false;

  @Output()
  showChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  hide(){
    this.show = false;
    this.showChange.emit(this.show);
  }
```

```
<app-show-hide [(show)]="show"></app-show-hide>
```

The `show` property from child do not pointing to same prop in the parent comp, because it's primitive value.
I don't recommend to modify data that not belong to child component (reference type, eg: object, array), it can lead to unexpected behavior.

Online demo with reference type (*be careful when modify ref type*): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhxgpo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshow-hide-obj%2Fshow-hide-obj.component.ts[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhxgpo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshow-hide-obj%2Fshow-hide-obj.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem because your child component modify Input value within your child component scope so no way parent component know the data is change

Your child component

```
   export class ShowHideComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input('show') show: boolean;
      @Output() updateShowValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<
        any
        >();
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.show);
      }

      hide() {
        this.updateShowValue.emit(!this.show);
      }
    }
```

In the app.component.html

```
<app-show-hide [show]="show" (updateShowValue)="update($event)"></app-show-hide>
```

And app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  show:boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.show = false;
    console.log(this.show)
  }
  showComp(){
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  update(event) {
    this.show = event;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that, but when I hide the component using "hide" button in  child component, then I have to click "Show" button twice to show the child component again. I have updated the stack blitz. Please check.Thanks!

Comment: No. Will that fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an @Output in your child component, when you click the hide button (in the child component) you need to notify your parent component and change the value of show variable to false, this is done with the EventEmitter.
Changes to made are :

> ShowHideComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-hide',
  templateUrl: './show-hide.component.html'
})
export class ShowHideComponent {
  @Input('show') show : boolean;
  @Output('') hideEE = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  hide(){
    this.hideEE.emit(false);
  }

}
```

> AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  show:boolean  = false;

}
```

> appComponent.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="show = true">Show</button>

<app-show-hide [show]="show" (hideEE)="show = $event"></app-show-hide>
```

stackblitz [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfjkmu)